# Detect external window update

Tags: window, gtk, x11, detect, window-managers

I would like to detect when an external window is updated|redrawn. In other words, I want to catch some kind of an event whenever a specified window (not of my app) changes its content (e.g. by updating nested image, displaying new text message, layout change etc.). This question applies both to X11/GTK and win32 based systems. Do you know any way to achieve this?

Comment: You need to copy the window pixel buffer periodically and compare it with the old copy. There are no special events for that.

Comment: That's the worst case scenario... Thanks anyway.

Comment: I always forget about all those newfangled extensions. :( Of course you can use Damage in X11 (dunno about win32).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With X11 you need to use Damage extension - `DamageCreate` / `DamageSubtract` requests and `DamageNotify` event. Not sure about gtk api ( Ideally there should be wrapper around X11/Damage and win32 but not sure if it exist ) - try to look at [damage-event](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-damage-event)

Comment: Thanks, that looks promising. I'm going to check it, and if it works, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: I've checked your solution using the example you've already posted in a similar thread (using node-js implementation). It seems to work, although it's too sensitive for me. It tells me the window has changed even if I hover the mouse pointer over it. Is there any way to make it a bit less sensitive (react, let's say, only when the bigger part of the screen actually redraws)? Unfortunately the documentation is very poor... I'll accept your answer, as it is the solution to the problem I asked (although, not very useful right now due to the oversensitiveness). Thank you for your time.

Comment: That's quite strange, I don't think I had that kind of sencsitivity when I tried. I'll let you know if I have more info